# Mysql large table export size of 3GB

Tags: mysql

I need to export a table of size 3GB to another database. Both are on different server. 
When i tried to export using phpmyadmin tool, It leads to server error.
Also both database are on different servers. I need to export and import into other server.
Please advise.

Comment: have you tried using command line mysqldump ?

Comment: What table type is it? InnoDB? MyISAM?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqldump` if that is a possibility, archive it and copy it afterwards to the new server.

If `mysqldump` is not accessible, phpMyAdmin has a feature to export it already archived ... try with that.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides a tool exactly for this purpose:

```
commandline_of_your_choice#> mysqldump -uusername -p -hlocalhost DB_Name --single-transaction | mysql -uusername -p -hremotehost DB_Name
```

Simple as that :)